# Position camera inside three.js cube

Tags: javascript, camera, three.js

I'm starting learning three.js. I studied the Getting started section on the website and had a look to some examples, but I can't figure out many things.

What I'd like to do is to create a cube (a box) and put the camera in the middle of it, so that I would see the inner side of each face. Is this actually possible?

Looking at the documentation, various examples and on stackoverflow, right now I'm at this point:

```
var camera, scene, renderer;

var isUserInteracting = false,
    onMouseDownMouseX = 0, onMouseDownMouseY = 0,
    lon = 0, onMouseDownLon = 0,
    lat = 0, onMouseDownLat = 0,
    phi = 0, theta = 0;

init();
animate();

function init() {

    var container, mesh;

    container = document.getElementById( 'container' );

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1100 );
    camera.target = new THREE.Vector3(1, 1, 1);

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(7, 7, 7);
    geometry.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeScale(-1, 1, 1));


var material = [
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x8bf2a7 } ),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x1ad9a5 } ),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xdadcad } ),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xb1b1b1 } ),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x3a3a3a } ), // front
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xf5f5f5 } )
    ];
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(material) );

    scene.add( mesh );

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false );
    document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
    document.addEventListener( 'mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false );

    document.addEventListener( 'dragover', function ( event ) {

        event.preventDefault();
        event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';

    }, false );

    document.addEventListener( 'dragenter', function ( event ) {

        document.body.style.opacity = 0.5;

    }, false );

    document.addEventListener( 'dragleave', function ( event ) {

        document.body.style.opacity = 1;

    }, false );

    document.addEventListener( 'drop', function ( event ) {

        event.preventDefault();

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.addEventListener( 'load', function ( event ) {

            material.map.image.src = event.target.result;
            material.map.needsUpdate = true;

        }, false );
        reader.readAsDataURL( event.dataTransfer.files[ 0 ] );

        document.body.style.opacity = 1;

    }, false );

    //

    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

}

function onWindowResize() {

    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

}

function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {

    event.preventDefault();

    isUserInteracting = true;

    onPointerDownPointerX = event.clientX;
    onPointerDownPointerY = event.clientY;

    onPointerDownLon = lon;
    onPointerDownLat = lat;

}

function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {

    if ( isUserInteracting === true ) {

        lon = ( onPointerDownPointerX - event.clientX ) * 0.1 + onPointerDownLon;
        lat = ( event.clientY - onPointerDownPointerY ) * 0.1 + onPointerDownLat;

    }

}

function onDocumentMouseUp( event ) {

    isUserInteracting = false;

}

function onDocumentMouseWheel( event ) {

    // WebKit

    if ( event.wheelDeltaY ) {

        camera.fov -= event.wheelDeltaY * 0.05;

        // Opera / Explorer 9

    } else if ( event.wheelDelta ) {

        camera.fov -= event.wheelDelta * 0.05;

        // Firefox

    } else if ( event.detail ) {

        camera.fov += event.detail * 1.0;

    }

    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

}

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    update();

}

function update() {

    if ( isUserInteracting === false ) {

        // lon += 0.1;

    }

    lat = Math.max( - 85, Math.min( 85, lat ) );
    phi = THREE.Math.degToRad( 90 - lat );
    theta = THREE.Math.degToRad( lon );

    camera.target.x = 500 * Math.sin( phi ) * Math.cos( theta );
    camera.target.y = 500 * Math.cos( phi );
    camera.target.z = 500 * Math.sin( phi ) * Math.sin( theta );

    camera.lookAt( camera.target );

    camera.position.z = 3;
    /*
    // distortion
    camera.position.copy( camera.target ).negate();
    */

    renderer.render( scene, camera );

}
```

I can actually see the cube from the inside, but it's not exactly what I want. I'm trying to put the camera in the exact center of the room and I would it to rotate on itself, but I don't exactly how to precisely move it.

Comment: Do you get any error messages in the console?

Comment: no, just THREE.WebGLRenderer 70, which I think is normal

Answer (score 2):

If you look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bfb4smto/) the only difference is the material.

Comment and uncomment the following line to see the effect.

```
THREE.ImageUtils.crossOrigin = '';
```

Also you can read more at this [issue](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/432)

Comment: I think the path is correct, because if I try to change it, putting a non existing image, I get an error in the console

Comment: This actually helped me with the texture, but still remain the main question, which is to position the camera in the middle of the box. I've put together other code and I think I'm almost there, so I'll update my question

Comment: as you have it the box is centered around (0,0,0) and only its outsize is rendered. So if you put your camera at (0,0,0) you will not see anything.